# How to sum count on specific columns in sql

Tags: sql

I want to calculate specific sum of counts

```
select is_known_bot, count(*) 
FROM "public"."bus_request" 
where app_name = 'xxxxxx' and event_type <> 'browser_js' 
    and is_known_bot <>'' 
    and date <= GETDATE() and date>= GETDATE()-14 
group by is_known_bot
order by is_known_bot asc
```

I am getting the below table:

```
is_known_bot count
good          2
bad           3
Human         7
```

in the end, i want to get the below table:

```
is_known_bot count
bot         5
Human        7
```

Comment: You want all except Humans counted as bot?

Comment: Try to read about case-when-then construction. I believe that could help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE` instead the column `is_know_bot`

```
Case when is_know_bot = 'Human' then is_know_bot else 'Bot' end
```